# How to refer to a variable from a string in Python 2

Tags: python

I am trying to get a variable from a string in a class. What I mean is when you give an input that is the name of a class attribute, it finds that variable. e.g.

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, north):

Place2 = ""
Place1 = Place(Place2)
Place2 = Place(Place1)

ask = raw_input("direction")
currentPlace = Place1
if (ask=="north"):
    currentPlace=currentPlace.north
```

Comment: can you reread your question and reformulate? I is a bit unclear what do you want. What is the expected output?, or some pseudo code of the expected behariour.

Answer (score 3):

Use `getattr(currentPlace, 'north' )`

Also, `setattr()` works the same way to update an attribute. As well as `hasattr()` for checking if an attribute exists

Answer (score 3):

Proposing an example with Python 3 (because Python 2 will get deprecated) and by following the example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 22


a1 = A()

attribute_name = input("what attribute?: ")

result = getattr(a1, attribute_name, None)
print("Your attribute {} is: {}".format(attribute_name, result))
```

A specific run will yield:

```
what attribute?: x
Your attribute x is: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `getattr`.

Example:

```
class Place(object):

    def __init__(self, north):
        self.north = north

    def get(self, attr):
        return getattr(self, attr)

place = Place('here')
print(place.get('north'))
```

Output:

```
here
```

Comment: Bad practice in my opinion to redefine a ''get'' method in python

Comment: What do you mean "redefine"?

Comment: You are just passing through arguments to a static method (getattr), why not using getattr directly then?

Comment: That is not "redefining" `getattr`, since `getattr` is not even a method of a class; `__getattr__` is. In any case, there is an argument to be made that method call syntax is more intuitive.